# BLIP encoder-based

Tags: huggingface-transformers, caption, huggingface

I’m wanting to use BLIP for image captioning. How can I ensure that captions are generated by an encoder and not decoder? I’ve been using the huggingface model:https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/blip

Thanks!

I tried setting is_decoder=False in BlipConfigText to configure the model however, I can’t get my model to train.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The weights of your model are trained to work in a certain way, you can not simply turn a model into an encoder or a decoder and still expect meaningful results. Can you maybe explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If you consider the BLIP architecture (see https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.12086), I want to use only the Image-grounded text encoder. So, I want to "switch off" the Image-grounded text decoder. Would this make sense to do image captioning like this? Essentially I want a structured caption and not generative which a decoder outputs.

Comment: @NinaGrundlingh like a classification task?

Comment: Sort of. Like a multi classification task.